# C# NetworkStream ReadAsync, data split between buffers

Tags: c#, .net, task, tcpclient, networkstream

I'm currently using the ReadAsync method in NetworkStream, and thus far its been pretty stable. The problem occurs when the data received from the server is larger than the buffer itself.

ReadCallBack assumes that the buffer contains a complete and valid message, as a new buffer is created on every call to BeginAsyncRead. Thus, when the response is too large for one buffer, it gets split between multiple reads and thus multiple buffers.

My ReadCallBack then assumes each buffer is an independent message (instead of adding them together) and ends up failing the deserialization on both.

**My question is**, *what is the correct way to handle messages that are bigger than the size of the buffer, specially if you want to do the reads asynchronously?* 
A character itself could be split between two buffers so this gets quite tricky.

Below is my code for ReadAsync and ReadCallBack.

```
    public async Task ReadForever() {
        while(this.IsConnected) {
            await BeginAsyncRead();
        }
    }


    public async Task BeginAsyncRead() {
        if (this.Stream.CanRead) {
            try {
                ReceiverState readState = new ReceiverState(this.Stream);
                var task = this.Stream.ReadAsync(readState.buffer, 0, ReceiverState.bufferSize);
                await task.ContinueWith(bytesRead => ReadCallBack(bytesRead.Result, readState));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            }
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Unreadable stream");
        } 
    }

private void ReadCallBack(int numBytesRead, ReceiverState state) {
    if (numBytesRead > 0) {
        string payload = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, numBytesRead);
        string[] responses = payload.Split(new string[] {"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string res in responses){                    
            var t = Task.Run(() => this.OnRead(res));
        }
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Corrupted number of bytes received");
    }
}
```

Note : All responses sent by the server contain a newline at the end.
Note : ReadForever is called inside Task.Run, my application can receive messages from the server as notifications, thus I must always be reading for incoming messages (I don't know when a notification may arrive).

Comment: You wrote your solution at the end of the post; if the buffer doesn't have a newline as its last nonzero character then it's an incomplete buffer and its contents should be stored somewhere. Keep appending subsequent buffer contents until you've read something that is an entire message (ends with a newline). ps, removing empty entries does you no favours here, because a buffer that ends in a newline will have an empty last entry, but you then remove it and hence cannot tell the difference between a complete buffer and an incomplete one